# Dropping pre-order bonus weapons in DX: Human Revolution?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

When dropping the pre-order bonus weapons such as the sawed-off shotgun - will I get them back every chapter? Or do I have to keep them the whole time if O ever want to use them later?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most of the pre-order/DLC/booster-pack weapons can be purchased from some shops if (and only if) you have the booster-pack activated, so if you discard the one you are given you will be able to purchase another later.

The Wikia notes that for the [double-barrel shotgun](http://deusex.wikia.com/wiki/Huntsman_Silverback):

> This weapon is available straight away in the booster packs that come with the pre-ordered version of Deus Ex: Human Revolution and **purchasable from merchants later.**

There is also a DB Shotgun on a high shelf inside one of the security stations outside at the docks.

Comment: I also found at least one location where the pre-order weapon was simply laying in the game world. (Silenced Sniper Rifle in TYM building -- after saving the employee from the gas, activate the maintainence catwalk; it's in the corner of the 2nd H-shaped room)

Comment: Yeah, a few are like that, it seems. The wikia pages are handy here too, just look in the locations section if there is one, but the DB shotgun makes no mention, so I assume is shop only